# How do I open .qch files?

Tags: qt, file-format, qt5

I've installed the `qt5-doc` package but I'm not able to open the `.qch` files that I find in the `/usr/share/qt5/doc/` directory.

Do you know how I can do this?

I've tried using `qt5-assistant` like this: `assistant -collectionFile <help-file>.qhc` but that didn't show anything.

Comment: Try QT Assistent: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/assistant-quick-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

To read pre-installed documentation you have to run Qt Assistant without arguments `assistant` and then select needed category from the Contents tab.

To open custom `*.qch` file you have to:

1. download it

   ```
   cd /tmp
   wget https://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/qwt/qwt/6.0.1/qwt-6.0.1.qch
   ```
2. create new collection for it

   ```
   touch /tmp/my.qhc
   ```
3. register file in the new collection

   ```
   assistant -collectionFile /tmp/my.qhc -register /tmp/qwt-6.0.1.qch;
   ```
4. open Qt Assistant with new collection

   ```
   assistant -collectionFile /tmp/my.qhc
   ```

   and navigate to the newly created entry in Contents (*Qwt User's Guide 6.0.1* in my case).

---

Sources:

1. https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Creator_Documentation_Gallery
2. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/assistant-custom-help-viewer.html